# Is it correct to have a Window(View) parameter in ViewModel class method in C# wpf mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Lets say I have a wpf project with the following classes:

```
//Representing the View:
class SomeWindow:Window
{
   //...
}


class SomeWindowViewModel
{
    //...
    SomeWindow window;
    public void SomeMethod(ref SomeWindow window)
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Is it correct to have a reference of the SomeWindow class in the SomeWindowViewModel class if I want to use an architecture like MVVM?

I am asking this because I have some code written in WindowsForm and I have to rewrite it in wpf mvvm, but the back end of the application has a lot of references to all kind of windows form references, and it isn't written by me. And as far as I know the ViewModel must not know anything about the View.

Comment: You've answered your own question. This is exactly the tight coupling the MVVM pattern is trying to avoid. If you elaborate with what you're trying to accomplish, you might get some answers on the MVVM-y way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short answer: No.

the view can reference the viewmodel but viewmodel should never reference the view. dont rewrite your winforms in wpf. take a look at DataTemplate, Behaviors and Binding stuff.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should avoid that kind of coupling between View and View-Model.

One of the beautiful things about MVVM is the ability to design a VM that can then be used by multiple different views - or no view at all.

By not adding a reference to the **concrete** View into the VM you make sure you are able to fulfill the aforementioned statement.

That doesn't mean you are forbidden to interact with Views from a VM; actually the VM responsibility is exactly that, to bridge the interaction between the Model and the View.

There are multiple ways to do that, it's really about finding a flavour that suits you well. Eventing, having a mediator, have a view manager injected into the VM, etc.

Porting WinForms to WPF MVVM is challenging. It's a complete different way of working, redesigning is certainly needed.

Good luck with the challenge!